# WordPress > Get custom taxonomy from a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, post, types, filter

1. [Installed Custom Post Type UI wordpress plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)
2. Created a custom post type  = 'products'
3. Registered a custom taxonomy categories (different from category) using

**1. How to display all custom post types and have a filter above with categories that works as filter tabs?**

**2.How to loop in a custom template through the custom taxonomy 'categories' and display links?**

**HTML structure**

Custom Post type URL : 
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=categories&post_type=products

**PHP**

```
<?php get_term( $term, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?>

<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'categories'
);
$output = 'products'; // or names
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}  
?>

<?php 
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false

); 
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ); 
if ( $taxonomies ) {
  foreach ( $taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy . '</p>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to get all the terms of a custom taxonomy:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'categories',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
}
```

`$term` returns an array with the following structure:

```
array(
[0] => WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] =>
    [name] =>
    [slug] =>
    [term_group] =>
    [term_taxonomy_id] =>
    [taxonomy] =>
    [description] =>
    [parent] =>
    [count] =>
    [filter] =>
)
```

`$term_link` will give you the permalink to your taxonomy term archive.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/

---

Regarding your other question of how to implement filter tabs:
Check out this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/beautiful-taxonomy-filters/

Comment: I tried this but it still give me nothing also you haven't specified anywhere the custom post type.

Comment: You don't need the post type to get the terms of a taxonomy but if your WP Version is older than 4.5.0 you need to make a small change:
`$terms = get_terms( 'categories', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );`

Answer (score 1):

To find the taxonomies associated with a given post type, use the WordPress [`get_object_taxonomies()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/) function like this:

```php
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('post', 'objects');
```

`$taxonomies` will be an array of `WP_Taxonomy` objects. Omit the second argument to get an array of taxonomy slugs.

To query by a custom taxonomy, create a new WP_Query something like this:

```php
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'categories',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => ['your-term'],
        ],
    ],
];
$filterQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

While taxonomy associations can be declared on post_types using `register_post_type`, the association is optional and very weak. Internally, WordPress goes the other way and assigns post_types to Taxonomies.

Each Taxonomy has an `object_type` property which is an array of slugs for the post_types it knows about. Digging into the `register_post_type` source code, we see it calls `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` for each item in the  `taxonomies` argument property, then simply adds a slug to the Taxonomy's `object_type` array. This is the only time the post_type's taxonomy property is used. I prefer to declare post_types when registering the Taxonomy since it's closer to how WordPress works and misunderstanding that association caused me a lot of grief in the past.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for